# Is the financial advice on http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/ designed only for the high street consumer?

Tags: research

The website http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/ seems to have a lot of accessible information but a lot of it is clearly aimed at the high street consumer with financial advice focussing a lot on switching ISAs and seeking what the best deals are on the high street. For someone who wanted to take their financial and investing knowledge beyond that is it worth looking elsewhere for information or is http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/ still worth some time?

Comment: I'm making the figures up, but presumably 99% of consumers (maybe 99.99%?) are the ones interested in switching ISAs and the best high street deals, and these websites have to make money from commission and referral right? So investing in helping a tiny minority is probably not worth their while. Also that tiny minority is 1000 times more difficult to cater for well as the complexity of making good investment decisions in a complex world economy taking into account hugely variable personal circumstances is immense! Hence the rise of personal financial advisers.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it isn't a worthwhile site, but there seems to be one financial ideology for the high street consumer and another for 'the others'.  Its a bit like reading a book that helps you get a  job versus a book that helps you start a business.

Comment: No it's useful. My own finances take me far beyond that level, but hell, I still want to find the best credit cards, mortgages, etc, without spending all year searching or paying £500 quid to a mortgage broker, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't navigate to the bottom of the page, where they put down their disclaimers.

> We think it's important you understand the strengths and limitations of the site. We're a journalistic website and aim to provide the best MoneySaving guides, tips, tools and techniques, but can't guarantee to be perfect, so do note you use the information at your own risk and we can't accept liability if things go wrong.
>
> This info does not constitute financial advice, always do your own research on top to ensure it's right for your specific circumstances and remember we focus on rates not service.
>
> We don't AS a general policy investigate the solvency of companies mentioned (how likely they are to go bust), but there is a risk any company can struggle and it's rarely made public until it's too late (see the section 75 guide for protection tips).We often link to other websites, but we can't be responsible for their content.
>
> Always remember anyone can post on the MSE forums, so it can be very different from our opinion.

So they generally lay down the data for you to take an informed decision and not to take a decision based on their views. And it is wrong to blindly accept their views, but you should try to read from multiple sites, do your own research before putting your money into wherever you want.

Comment: Yeah. No such thing as free advice ;-)

Comment: my question, maybe I didn't word it well, is more about the kind of audience this information is aimed at which @Michael answered quite well in the post comment

Comment: but yeah useful point as it does say do your own research.

Comment: @AndrewWelch Frankly speaking it is for all who want to spend their hard earned money carefully and get the best out of their money. So who is it targeted at, becomes a moot point.

Comment: Presuming that everyone wants to get the best out of their money and that everyone's money is hard earned, but yeah I get your point. Perhaps the audience of this website combine those two attributes.